# Строительство автомобильной дороги и автомобильного подхода в г. Керчь или в г. КерчИ?

Tags: склонение

Строительство автомобильной дороги и автомобильного подхода в г.Керчь или в г. КерчИ? ....к транспортному переходу через 
Керченский пролив

Answer (score 1):

Строительство автомобильной дороги и автомобильного подхода **в г.Керчи.**

**Розенталь:** Названия городов, сел, деревень,  выраженные склоняемым существительным, **как правило, согласуются в падеже** с определяемым словом, например: в городе Москве, у города Смоленска, над городом Саратовом; в деревню Дюевку, через хутор Подбанку, в селе Ильинском.

Названия **не склоняются** в особой литературе (военной, географической, туристической) для сохранения точности наименования, а также  тех случаях, когда при склонении становится неясным род имени собственного: в городе Пушкино, Иваново,  Ровно.